# Error al acceder a un índice dentro de un string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola me gustaria que me corrijan este codigo ya que me sale IndexError: string index out of range en Python y tiene relacion con len() al parecer

```
import random
numeros = ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
codigo = ''
for i in range(4):
    jugador= random.choice(numeros)
    while jugador in codigo:
        jugador = random.choice(numeros)
        codigo = codigo + jugador

print("Bienvenido al juego Toque y Fama")
print("Consiste en adivinar un numero de", 4, "cifras diferentes")
eleccion = input("¿Que codigo eliges?: ")
intentos = 1
while eleccion != codigo:
    intentos = intentos + 1
    Famas = 0
    Toques = 0
    for i in range(4):
        if eleccion[i] == codigo[i]:
            Famas = Famas + 1
        elif eleccion[i] in codigo:
            Toques = Toques + 1
    print("Tu eleccion (", eleccion, ") tiene", Fama, \
          "Fama y ", Toques, "Toques.")
    eleccion = input("Plantea otro codigo: ")

print("Felicidades! Adivininaste el codigo en", intentos, "intentos.")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error proviene de la parte en que inicializas `codigo`, que tal como lo tienes escrito genera siempre una cadena vacía. Tienes esto:

```
codigo = ''
for i in range(4):
    jugador= random.choice(numeros)
    while jugador in codigo:
        jugador = random.choice(numeros)
        codigo = codigo + jugador
```

En la primera iteración se genera un dígito al azar, digamos `'3'`. Ya que ese dígito no está en el `codigo`, no entra en el `while`. Ya que la instrucción que añade el dígito al `codigo` la tienes dentro del while, no se añade. El `codigo` está siempre vacío.

Lo que querías hacer es meter el dígito en el código **después** del bucle (que es sólo para asegurarse de que no hay dígitos repetidos). Es decir:

```
codigo = ''
for i in range(4):
    jugador= random.choice(numeros)
    while jugador in codigo:
        jugador = random.choice(numeros)
    codigo = codigo + jugador
```

Aparte de eso, más adelante usas la variable `Fama` donde querías decir `Famas`

### Posible mejora

Para generar un valor para `codigo` sin dígitos repetidos y sin tener que reintentar (pues puedes tener mala suerte, salirte muchas veces seguidas dígitos repetidos y perder un rato en el `while`), puedes usar `random.sample()`:

```
numeros = "0123456789"
codigo = "".join(random.sample(numeros, 4))
```